# TCP Connection, 6 Packets, Probability of certain arrival orders

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

So I have a *very* hard time with statistics and probability. This comes from not being able to extract what I need to do from the given information. I don't get why I can't solve such easy stuff... :(

Anyway, the task:

> A PC on a network has an established TCP-Connection (no packets are
>   lost). Our program waits for data which comes in exactly 6 packets.
>
> Those packets are D1 through D6. The order at with they arrive is
>   random.
>
> What is the probability of
>
> 1. D1 arriving first?
> 2. D2 arriving after D1? (edit: somewhere after, not just directly after D1)
> 3. this arrival order: D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6?

The solution I got sounds stupidly easy.

1. Looks like Laplace to me, so each packet should have $p=\frac{1}{6}$ which in this case is the solution?
   **P("D1 arrives first") = $\frac{1}{6}$**
2. This one is the most complex of the three I guess. I think I have to find all combinations where D2 arrives after D1. Those are quite a few. **How do I get this number? What to do after I have it?**
3. This one I think is **P("All packets in correct order") = $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{720}$**

I am very insecure with my approaches with statistics, if it weren't for my really bad prof I'd really like to dig deeper since I am quite interested in data science. In two weeks time I have to prove that I can do this...

Comment: By symmetry the probability for the second is $\frac{1}{2}$. (I am assuming follows does not necessarily mean directly follows, that it means comes sometime after.) The other two  questions have the right answers. The answer for the first is $\frac{1}{6}$ by symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your assumption is correct, I will clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can represent each arrival order by one permutation of the packets $\{D1,\ldots,D6\}$. If all $6!$ orders are equally likely (which further means that the probability of each order is $1/6!$), then

1. The packet $D1$ arrives first in $5!$ orders that have $D1$ in the first place, and the probability of this event is therefore $5! \times 1/6! = 1/6$.
2. Let us associate to each arrival order $A$ another arrival order $B$ by swapping places of $D1$ and $D2$ in $A$. In this way, to each arrival order where $D1$ precede $D2$ corresponds another arrival order where $D2$ precede $D1$ and vice versa, so there is equal number of them, and the probability that $D1$ comes before $D2$ (as well as the probability that $D2$ comes before $D1$) is $1/2$.
3. We initially assumed that each arrival order is equally likely and therefore occurs with probability $1/6!$ (since there are 6! different orders), so this is also the case for this specific order $D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am thinking too complicated... :)